# How to make DateTime.TryParse() fail if no year is specified?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Consider the following code to parse a date. (Note that I'm in the EN-gb locale):

```
const DateTimeStyles DATE_TIME_STYLES = DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault | DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces;
DateTime dt;

// Current culture for this example is "EN-gb".

if (DateTime.TryParse("31/12", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DATE_TIME_STYLES, out dt))
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed correctly"); // Do not want!
else
    Console.WriteLine("Did not parse correctly.");
```

I'm deliberately omitting the year. However, `TryParse()` will parse this without any errors, and will substitute the current year.

I'd like to be able to force the user to enter ALL the components of the date (using their local format), so I'd like the above parsing to fail - or to be able to detect that the user didn't enter a year.

I don't really want to use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` because then I would have to add code to specify all the different valid formats for all the different supported locales, which is non-trivial and likely error-prone. I suspect this may well be my only sane option, though.

Anyone got any ideas? (Someone here at work has already implemented a "solution" which involves not allowing the current year, which is clearly not a good solution...)

Comment: Along the lines of your co-workers "solution" you could create an extension method that chains to tryparse after confirming there is a day, month and year component to the datetime.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal That's harder than you may think, since the user could type something like "2014 Jan 15" or "31 Jan 12" which should parse correctly, but if I wanted to parse that I'd have to parse the month name etc, which is a lot of work that I hope to avoid...

Comment: I have a clever work around for that which will be much like your co-workers solution but not so retarded :p   It's still not full-proof but the best I can offer.

Comment: Just a thought - If you're certain the input is only a date (as opposed to a date and time), you can count the number of items in the string (in addition to checking TryParse was successful).

Comment: Why you don't check the length of the input?

Comment: How would you interpret `03/04`? as 3rd April or 4th March? because that's why you are avoiding TryParseExact() as you do not know the format i guess. Even if you somehow get it to work, how would you test the output??

Comment: @Abhi the culture info `TryParse` requires is being passed in from somewhere else (actually, .NET/Windows is getting it for him check the docs on `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`). The OP doesn't want to write a function that uses a switch statement with one case for every culture info.

Comment: What about `DateTimeFormatInfo`? You could combine these with `TryParseExact`. Not sure if it contains all valid formats for a culture, but it at least has `LongDatePattern` and `ShortDatePattern`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could query for the culture's patterns, filter out those without a year and then use `TryParseExact` on the remaining patterns.

```
var allPatterns = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
var patternsWithYear = allPatterns.Where(s => s.Contains("y")).ToArray();
bool success = TryParseExact(input, patternsWithYear, culture, styles, out dateTime);
```

Known bug: This doesn't take escaping into account, you'll need to replace the `Contains("y")` call with proper parsing to fix this.

Alternatively you could go with just `LongDatePattern` and `ShortDatePattern` if you're fine with stricter format constraints.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this (but in truth I'd like to go back to the UI requirements and suggest that either we relax this requirement or we use a proper Calendar control, which would be better all round!)

Answer (score 4):

You can use parse exact like this and catch the exception.

`CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` will give you the cultures short date pattern.

There is also `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), cultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString, cultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
```

Comment: Use the culture's DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern property.

Answer (score 2):

The more I think about this the more I think it's a bad solution but given you're getting no other answers I'll post it anyway.

```
DateTime temp;
DateTime.TryParse(input, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, DATE_TIME_STYLES, out temp);

if (temp.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
{
    if (!input.Contains(DateTime.Now.Year))
    {
        if (temp.Days != int.Parse(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().SubString(2)))
        {
             // my god that's gross but it tells you if the day is equal to the last two
             // digits of the current year, if that's the case make sure that value occurs
             // twice, if it doesn't then we know that no year was specified
        } 
    }
}
```

Also, as others have suggested in comments now, checking the number of tokens or the strings length could also be useful like;

```
char[] delims = new char[] { '/', '\', '-', ' '); //are there really any others?
bool yearFound = false;

foreach (char delim in delims)
{
    if (input.Split(delim).Count == 3)
    {
         yearFound = true;
         break;
    }
}

if (yearFound)
    //parse
else
    // error
```

These are just a couple of ideas, neither is truly sound. They're obviously both hacks, only you can know if they'll suffice. At least they beat your co-workers `if (dt.Year == 2014) //discard input` "solution".