# C# make DateTime.TryParse() NOT assume year

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-parsing

The `DateTime.TryParse()` method in C# will assume current year if there's no year specified.
I want a function that will return `false` if the year is not specified (and not assume).

I cannot use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` because I don't know the format - I want it to work in general just like `DateTime.TryParse()`.

These test cases should return `false`:

```
"3/15"
"Dec 16,"
"4-11"
"Thursday Aug 6"
"Sept-9"
```

These test cases should return `true`:

```
"11/22/2016"
"Wed Jan 1, 2021"
"9-2-16"
"Aug.5.2018"
"2.28.1996"
```

Comment: Aside from the year issue, how do you know that `TryParse` will get it right? Is 9-2-16 2016/02/09, 2016/09/02, or perhaps 2009/02/16?

Comment: Perhaps this existing SO post will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485261/how-to-make-datetime-tryparse-fail-if-no-year-is-specified

Comment: You have no idea the can of worms you are opening.

Comment: I agree with John and Joel.  One cannot just take a string of something that looks like or might be a date and parse it intelligibly.  Context is key, especially with regard to locale.  If you don't know *any* of the possible formats, your screwed.  If you have a list of formats, then you can use that to achieve your goal.

Comment: I don't understand all the worry. I want to take an existing function and make it MORE robust by NOT assuming the year. I'd rather the function fail than assume.

Comment: Still not sure exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps you could pass `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` and then separately check for `year == 1`.  Though that would assume you didn't want an actual year 1 to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse unknown date format. The `TryParseExact` is trying to parse a string to `DateTime` with exact format. I would suggest you to work with different formats you have specified like this

```
using System.Globalization;

var formats = new[] {"MM/dd/yyyy", "ddd MMM d, yyyy", "M-d-yy", "MMM.d.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy", "M.d.yyyy"};
foreach(var format in formats)
{
     bool isValidDateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateText, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value);
     if (isValidDateTime) 
     {
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Note that `"MM.dd.yyyy"` is redundant because it's covered by `"M.d.yyyy"`.

Comment: You don't need the `for each` loop as `TryParseExact` will take a string array of formats. But mentioned above by @wazdev [this is what you probably want.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486535/3585500)